# Stata: removing line feed control characters

Tags: stata, linefeed

I have a dataset which I export with command `outsheet` into a csv-file. There are some rows which breaks line at a certain place. Using a hexadecimal editor I could recognize the control character for line feed "0a" in the record. The value of the variable producing the line break shows visually (in Stata) only 5 characters. But if I count the number of characters:

```
gen xlen = length(x)
```

I get 6. I could write a Perl programm to get rid of this problem but I prefer to remove the control characters in Stata before exporting (for example using `regexr()`). Does anyone have an idea how to remove the control characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `char()` function calls up particular ASCII characters. So, you can delete such characters by replacing them with empty strings.

```
replace x = subinstr(x, char(10), "", .)
```

Comment: A Stata command `charlist` to identify which characters occur in strings is downloadable via `ssc inst charlist`. Its main use is to identify problematic characters such as linefeeds.

Comment: `charlist` does what was intended, but people should note the much more versatile `chartab`,  also from SSC.  Similarly this post is out of date insofar as Stata now supports Unicode. `help string functions` reveals a toolkit of relevant functions.